# How can I install Dog Tail

Tags: automation

Does anyone have a detailed and accurate reference on how to install DogTail?

I tried to install it, but I come up against problems.

Comment: What kind of problems did you run into?

Comment: You mentioned Ubuntu 11; is that 11.04 or 11.10?

Answer (score 3):

dogtail is a GUI test tool and automation framework written in Python.  It uses Accessibility (a11y) technologies to communicate with desktop applications. dogtail scripts are written in Python.

To install python-dogtail in Ubuntu 11.10-18.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt -y install python-dogtail
```